# Failed save update Profile Form Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

i want to validate a form using isValid but there's a problem that im unable to find is there anything wrong here?
btw if i just check user_form.is_valid and try to change password, it will work
but profile_form is not working

when i use print(profile_form.errors)
in cmd will show `<ul class="errorlist"><li>email<ul class="errorlist"><li>This Field Cannot be left blank</li></ul></li><li>nomor_hp<ul class="errorlist"><li>This Field Cannot be left blank</li></ul></li><li>email2<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>`

this is my web look like [image: when i press edit, they will show form to update]

this is my views

```
@login_required(login_url='pengurusan/signin')
def post_update(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
    userr = User.objects.filter(id=pk)
    profilee = Profile.objects.filter(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #print(request.POST)
        user_form = PasswordChangeForm(user = request.user , data=request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            return render(request, 'pengurusan/index.html')
    user_form = PasswordChangeForm(user = request.user , data=request.POST)
    profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=user.profile)
    context={
        "user_form" : user_form,
        "profile_form" : profile_form,
        "user" : user,
        "userr" : userr,
        "profile" : user.profile,
        "profilee" : profilee,
    }
    return render(request, 'pengurusan/update-form.html', context)
```

this is my form

```
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('email', 'username', 'password')
    widgets = { 'email' : forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'exampleInputEmail', 'placeholder' : 'Email Address', 'name' : 'email'}),
                'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control form-control-user', 'id' : 'exampleFirstName', 'placeholder' : 'username', 'name' : 'username'})
    }
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['nama', 'nik', 'email', 'nomor_hp']
        widgets = { 'nama': forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'id' : 'exampleFirstName', 'placeholder' : 'Name'}),
                    'nik' : forms.NumberInput(attrs={'id' : 'exampleLastName', 'placeholder' : 'Nomor Identitas Penduduk'}),
                    'email' : forms.EmailInput(attrs={'id' : 'exampleInputEmail', 'placeholder' : 'Email Address', 'name' : 'email'}),
                    'nomor_hp' : forms.NumberInput(attrs={'size':'4', 'maxlength':'12', 'class':'phone', 'placeholder' : 'Nomor Handphone'}),
        }
```

and this is my models

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    nama = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    nik = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75, blank=True)
    nomor_hp = models.TextField(max_length=15, blank=True)    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

this is my urls.py if you need it

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.signin), 
    url(r'index/$', views.index),
    url(r'signin/$', views.signin),
    url(r'signup/$', views.signup),
    url(r'signout/$', views.signout),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit/$', views.post_update, name='post_update'),
    path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>', views.VerificationView.as_view(), name="activate"),
    path('request-reset-link', views.RequestPasswordResetEmail.as_view(), name="request-password"),
    path('set-new-password/<uidb64>/<token>', views.CompletePasswordReset.as_view(), name="reset-user-password"),
]
```

Comment: add your post_update's url and PasswordChangeForm

Comment: already updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in

```
profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
```

you passed the request.user but, your ProfileForm is for profil not user,
the instance is wrong, so change by profil instance

```
profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
```

Comment: i got this 'User' object has no attribute 'profil' @rgermain

Comment: i already use request.user.profile but still cannot save the update, i think profile_form still not valid @rgermain

Comment: i got this in cmd `<ul class="errorlist"><li>email<ul class="errorlist"><li>This Field Cannot be left blank</li></ul></li><li>nomor_hp<ul class="errorlist"><li>This Field Cannot be left blank</li></ul></li><li>email2<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>` 

so its mean i can't  input the form one by one?

Comment: i already solved it, i costumize my html, thanks for your help